# Is it possible to make a specific branch public in Gitlab (or other Git repository management tool)?

Tags: git, gitlab, gitolite

We want to set up a Git repository so that the master branch is public, but we can develop feature branches internally (and merge them into master as required). Looking at Gitolite description, it's possible, but does any repository manager tool (such as GitLab) expose this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitLab has **[various permissions](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/permissions/permissions.md)**, including one for protecting branches.

So you could emulate a public branch by actually protecting the branches which aren't public.
(`project -> commits -> branches -> protected`)

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to specify that all branches are protected by default and to make branches public explicitly?

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov no, for now GitLab only offers one way (specify protected branches), not the other way around.

Answer (score 2):

I recommending to do the following:
Install gitlab ro stash or any other tool that you like to use.
Develop all your work internally,

add new remote to git and publish you work to this remote. this remote can be hosted on github for example so your work will be public.